# How to use Quadratic Theory to determine the gradient of a tangent to a reciprocal function?

Tags: calculus

Provided the reciprocal function is in the form $y=\frac{a}{x}$, it is possible to determine the gradient of the tangent to a given point on the function using quadratic theory, but how?

I have seen many worked solutions of the type $y=x^2$, where $x^2=mx+k$, as the tangent shares a common point where $y=mx+k$ meets $y=x^2$. From this relationship $a=1$, $b=-m$, $c=-k$, according to the quadratic form $y=ax^2 + bx + c$. Given that the discriminant, $\Delta=0$ when seeking the tangent, this is then substituted into the now simplified form of the quadratic formula, $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$ for a given value of $x$ to determine the gradient, $m$ (e.g. if we are seeking the tangent at $(1,1)$ then $1=-\frac{-m}{2}$, resulting in $m = 2$).

Without resorting to differentiation, how is the same principal applied to the reciprocal form? I'm struggling and any help would be greatly appreciated. Let's use $y=\frac{4}{x}$ at the point $(1,4)$ as an example to work on....

Answer (score 0):

For the function $y = 4/x$, the tangent satisfies
$$
\frac 4x = mx + k.
$$
Multiplying by $x$ and collecting terms on the right, this becomes a quadratic equation:
$$
0 = mx^2 + kx - 4  \tag 1
$$
Setting the discriminant to zero,
$$
k^2 + 16 m = 0. \tag2
$$
On the other hand, if we set $x=1$ in equation $(1)$,
$$
m + k - 4 = 0.
$$
Substitute $m=-k+4$ in equation $(2)$:
$$
k^2 - 16k + 64 = 0,
$$
which has only one solution, $k=8$, and therefore $m=-4$.

More generally, multiply equation $(2)$ by $x^2$,
$$
k^2 x^2 + 16 mx^2 = 0,
$$
and make the subsitution $mx^2 = -kx + 4$ (based on equation $(1)$)
to obtain
$$
k^2 x^2 - 16kx + 64 = 0,
$$
which factors as
$
(kx - 8)^2 = 0,
$
so $k = 8/x$. Substituting this into equation $(1)$,
we get $0 = mx^2 + 4$, and therefore (if $x\neq0$)
$$
m = - \frac{4}{x^2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, David. You're explanation is superbly clear and it all makes perfect and logical sense. I greatly appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Since posting this question, I've developed a third possible method on top of the two suggested by David...

From $(1)$ in David's answer we equate $a=m, b=k, c=-4$ and substitute into $x= \frac{-b}{2a}$

Therefore, $$x= \frac{-k}{2m} \tag 2$$

Since we are looking for the tangent at $(1,4)$, sub $x=1$ into $(2)$, and solve in terms of $k$, $$k=-2m \tag 3$$

Sub point $(1,4)$ into the slope equation $y=mx+k$, and solve in terms of $k$, $$k=4-m \tag 4$$

Sub $(3)$ into $(4)$, $$-2m=4-m$$

Therefore, $$m=-4$$